# how to direct a user to a url using a user input javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to any kind of coding and was wondering if anyone could help me out as this is a major part of my website.

Also I am using a website creator (Wix.com) as I don't really know much coding, which means I can only use html/javascript

what I'm after doing is having a user input box that requires a reference number that I will be sending out with my products, when submitted I want it to take them to the relevant page e.g. my site is http://www.scotttaylor1989.wix.com/authenticproducts (soon to be www.authentic-products.com) and say the reference number is 123456789 when submit is clicked i want it to take them to scotttaylor1989.wix.com/authenticproducts/123456789 (www.authentic-products.com/123456789) ill obviously change the code when my site address changes.

On the other hand say 987654321 is NOT a reference number and they enter it and click submit I want an alert to pop up saying invalid reference number.

Below is what I have so far not much I know but javascript baffles me :/, I've been searching the internet for days and can't find a solution as everyone is doing it using php, any help would be much appreciated ;)

I don't want the code given to me as I want to learn how it works I've looked around www.w3schools.com but just don't know how its done.

```
<form name="RefChecker">

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Reference Number" name="ref">

<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="gotoref()"?

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function gotoref()
{

}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. use the form submit event and not the click event. Return false from the submit event to not submit the form
2. If you do not user a server process you need to store the reference number in the page which can easily be viewed by looking at the source. Is that ok?

You ask for suggestions but no code so here is my suggestion

A solution that might work for you is to put an image on the server called 123456789.gif

In the submit event of the form you can load an image with the value in the field+"gif" and return false to cancel the submission

onerror of the gif alert the error, onload, change the location to "/"+value of field

Comment: ok thanks im still learning through w3schools and im not mithered about people seeing the pages theres nothing of any value on there just references to a specific product, iv set it up so iv got a web page for each reference number so i just need to build up the page location. As for validation its not that important atm i can implement that later when iv learnt abit more

Comment: Please note that w3schools are not the greatest resource out there. I prefer MDN. So do you need more help? Also do me a personal favour and write **I**, **I've** and **I'm** using capital personal pronoun and start all sentences with a capital letter. It makes it much easier to read and is not harder to write

Comment: Ok sorry i will do and ill have a look at MDN aswell then. Ill post what code i have at around 18:00(GMT) if i still cant get it working

Comment: Downvoting without commenting is pure harassment